# Why does cv2.medianBlur returns a format error?

Tags: python, image, opencv, median

I am trying to use the cv2.medianBlur on an image but it does not work unless I import the image using the cv2.read. As I don't want to change the rest of my code can anyone explain to me why this happens or any other method to accomplish the same result?

```
def medianFilterData(data, w):
    fdata = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        img = data[i].astype('d')
        median = cv2.medianBlur(img, w)
        fdata.append(median)
    return fdata
```

The error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/median_blur.simd.hpp:975: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'cv::opt_AVX2::medianBlur'
```

The first image is:
[image]

Comment: It happens because despite the documentation of `medianBlur` clearly saying that "the image depth should be CV_8U, CV_16U, or CV_32F" you're giving it an array you explicitly converted into 64bit floats.

Answer (score 3):

try `.astype('int8')` or `.astype('float32')`

```
def medianFilterData(data, w):
    fdata = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        img = data[i].astype('int8')
        median = cv2.medianBlur(img, w)
        fdata.append(median)
    return fdata
```

Comment: 'int8' did not work but 'float32' did the job! Thank you so much!